# Colour by Row Dimension and Quartile Qlik Sense

Tags: qliksense, sense

[Pivot Table As is Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR7rR.png)

Hi all,

In Qlik Sense. How do I colour by the lower level dimension instead of all. (Background expression for measure). Stack will only let me attach the image as a link. Sorry about that.

At the moment. My syntax is this: if (Fractile([DeliveryVolume], 0.25) > 0.25, if(Fractile([DeliveryVolume], 0.75) < 0.75, green(), red()), red()). It colours all three of the row dimensions, it is just the lower level one I want to colour.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`Dimensionality()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/InterRecordFunctions/dimensionality.htm):

```
=if( Dimensionality() = 3
, if (Fractile([DeliveryVolume], 0.25) > 0.25, if(Fractile([DeliveryVolume], 0.75) < 0.75, green(), red()), red())
)
```

Comment: Life saver. Thank you ever so much!

Comment: Happy to help! Just remember to mark as correct :)